# two menu's shown on the initial loading of page

Tags: angular, typescript

Main Menu is visible when the app is started. I would also like Menu One to be visible at this point also.

I feel my code is overly complex so finding it difficult to add this functionality.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3q8e8q

```
data = SideMenu.data.subOptions[0].children;
// selected: number;
selected: number = 0;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}
showSubMenu(item: {}, i: number) {
   console.log(item['children']);
   this.selected = i;
   this.changeMainMenu.emit(item['children']);
}
```

Hoping to have Main Menu and Sub Menu One visible on start.

Sub Menu Two should not be visible at this point.

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this. From which point on should menu two be visible?

Comment: @LeBavarois Menu Two should only be visible after an option on Menu One has been clicked - so this is working fine for the moment.
Note: the style is only applied to Menu One once it has been clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `showSubMenu` method on the `ngOnInit()` and pass the first item and index 0 for showing the first item of main menu and it's children. This will emit your event and will display the sub menu on page load.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.showSubMenu(this.data[0], 0);
}
```

Comment: @Ana_30 I am glad it help. Best of luck.